# Why do my answers keep getting an error?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Trying to post an answer to a question in main EE StackOverflow, I will get "an error occurred" without more specifics.
Posting comments works fine.
Why is that? Something going on? Something with my account?

The specific error is a red box right next to the submit post button saying "An error occurred submitting the answer."

And, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Seems to have started recently.

Comment: Could you try to provide some more specifics on your particular setup? There isn't an administrative reason why you should be having issues.

Comment: I was getting much the same, see other post -- http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/getting-error-occured-submitting-the-answer-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry 'bout that. I broke a thing earlier today. This should be fixed now.